# jquery remove class from div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I am trying to remove a class from a DIV however all I am able to do is add a new class along side the one I'm trying to remove. How do I remove `fullpage-wrapper` completely?

```
<script>
  jQuery('#productPage').addClass('test3-test').removeClass('fullpage-wrapper');
</script>
```

Comment: Can you show before and after if you just use `removeClass(name)`?

Comment: add this script in $(function(){//your code});

Comment: Lot of questions will raise like, you wrapped your code into dom ready block?, you linked the jquery library properly?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle showing the issue?

Comment: I dont think a fiddle will help, He probably just needs to wrap the js in a `$(document).ready(function(){});`. JSfiddle does this by default.

Comment: Maybe you are adding the class fullpage-wrapper somewhere after the execution of that code

Comment: Those suggesting it needs a doc.ready or a closure:  note that apparently it is successfully *adding* a class, but not successfully *removing* one.  (My money's on the `fullpage-wrapper` being added back by other code after this one executes)

Answer (score 0):

Just added some comments to explain procedure

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#demo").addClass("demo"); //add class "demo" to div "demo"
    });

   $("#remove").click(function(){
        $("#demo").removeClass("demo"); //remove class "demo" from div "demo"
    });
});
```

```css
.demo{
  background: red;
height:50px;
width:250px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="demo">This is a demo</div>

<button id="add">Add Class</button>
<button id="remove">Remove Class</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is this? How about some text explaining your answer instead of just a code dump?

Comment: I'm not sure changing the single-line add+remove  into two separate click handlers has much to do with the question at all.  They clearly know that `addClass()` and `removeClass()` exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must put your js code in a `$(document).ready(function(){// here your js code});)`

Like this your js code will be exécute once your html page is loaded.